# reactjs this context is changed inside on change method how call function

Tags: reactjs, this, listeners

This is change, when I call on, event listener (instead of on onClick method in an element, because I use bootstrap select2).

```
getReviewVacancyUpdate(post_id) {
    console.log(post_id);
}

componentDidMount() {
   $('#post_list').on('change', function(e) {          
       this.getReviewVacancyUpdate(this.value); //function in undefined
   });
}
```

Is it anyway to save previous this state? Maybe bind it? And call the component method. Without error - "`function is undefined`"

I can add class to the beginning of jsx.

```
var Child = React.createClass({
statics: {
    getReviewVacancyUpdate: function(post_id) { 
        console.log(post_id);
        return true;
    }
},
// ...
render() {

}
});
```

But it doesn't look good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i  add let variable to save this context before on change method invokes. And everything works fine.

```
componentDidMount() {
     let save_this = this;
     $('#post_list').on('change', function(e){
           let selected = $(e.currentTarget).find("option:selected").val();
           save_this.getReviewVacancyUpdate(selected);
     }).bind(this);
}
```